# How does POST /_cache/clear works in Open search?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I am executing one query, for first time it is taking 6 7 sec.
After running second time it took only 1 sec.

I check clear cache options on OpenSearch documentation.
But I can not see any query performance as it is taking only 1 sec.

I tried to clear cache and checked stats of cluster but it is showing like "memory_size_in_bytes":0 before clearing cache and even after clearing cache.

What I can do if I want to clear cache and run same query again and again?

Comment: can you share `GET /_nodes/stats/indices/request_cache?human&pretty&filter_path=**.*cache*`
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shard-request-cache.html